# OpenCL and CUDA kernels on same GPU

Tags: cuda, opencl

I'm new to this technology. I have an application which consists of OpenCL kernel and CUDA kernel. I want to execute OpenCL kernel and CUDA kernel one after another on the same GPU(Tesla M2050). Is it possible to execute.?

If it is possible, do we need to take care of any memory management.?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you meaning within the same application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to run OpenCL kernels and CUDA Kernels from the same application. Each has its own schedulers. Memory management will be taken care by the GPU Driver.

Comment: OpenCL and CUDA will run in separate GPU contexts. GPU memory cannot be shared as their is no OpenCL CUDA interop layer. The GPU will context switch between execution of work between the two APIs.